# bin/sh -c:line 1 Syntax Error:unexpected end of file on Crystax NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

After switching my Android NDK from android-ndk-r8b (official) to android-ndk-r7-crystax-5.beta2 (unofficial Crystax build), my NDK builds from within Eclipse (ADT) started failing immediately with:

```
bin/sh -c:line 1 Syntax Error:unexpected end of file
```

Builds from the command line (i.e. running `ndk-build.cmd`) work as usual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a quick analysis (with Sysinternals Proccess Monitor -- NDK's own verbose logging did little to help me), I've seen make.exe calling c:\cygwin\bin\sh.exe with what was clearly a DOS batch command(!):

```
C:/cygwin/bin/sh.exe -c "if not exist \"obj\local\armeabi\\\" md \"obj\local\armeabi\\\""
```

While I did not have C:\Cygwin\bin on my PATH (this is a bad idea -- causes incompatibilities with batch files), but Eclipse ADT prepended C:\Cygwin\bin into the project's PATH :-( Once I removed C:\cygwin\bin from the path, the problem was solved.

To solve this problem:

1. In Eclipse, open the project's context menu, go to the *Project Properties | C/C++ Build | Environment*
2. Edit the PATH environment variable and remove `"C:\cygwin\bin;"` from its beginning.
3. (The origin will change from *BUILD SYSTEM* to *USER; CONFIG*)
4. Build!